# Differential equations describing a physical system - deriving the equations and elaborating on such equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

We see the mass-and-spring system above and we derive two systems of differential equations to describe its behavior.

For example, we have

$$m_2 y^{\prime \prime} = k_2 x - (k_2 + k_3)y$$

I have two questions:

**1. Is there any formal method of deriving these differential equations? As I usually only rely on looking at the figure and deriving them myself.**

**2. For the equation aforementioned, why do we only include $k_2 x$? Wouldn't there be another force acting on the system caused by the stretching of the spring represented by $k_1$, which would add a $-k_1 x$ term to the equation? Or is that force somehow cancelled?**

Comment: The equation for a block should only include forces from things touching that block.  The first spring does not touch the second block, so the $k_1x$ term only shows up for the first block.  But don't worry, as it moves the first block it pulls on the second spring, which will affect the second block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a more formal way that takes a  lot of guessing out: the Lagrange equations (formalism), and the Hamilton equations (the so-called analytical mechanics).
2. When you write the motion for mass $2$, note that the only forces that act on it are through the two springs. All you need is to figure out the signs correctly. Namely: if the spring $k_3$ is elongated to the right of equilibrium position (compressed), it will act on mass $2$ towards the left of the axis $Oy$, hence $-k_3 y$. The spring $k_2$ is *compressed* by $y-x$ (contributing to the total force as $-k_2 (y-x)$ (imagine if you were replacing mass $2$ and $y>x$, which way you would feel the pull).